# scikit-learn fit function classification

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using the fit function for classification training in  scikit-learn. 
For example, while using random forests, one typically uses the following type of code:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RF
forest=RF(n_estimators=10)
forest=forest.fit(TrainingX,Trainingy)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error when using Python 3:

> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:175: DeprecationWarning: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated, use inspect.signature() instead forest=forest.fit(
>     args, varargs, kw, default = inspect.getargspec(init)
>
> C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:175: DeprecationWarning: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated, use inspect.signature() instead
>     args, varargs, kw, default = inspect.getargspec(init)

Does anyone know what this error means?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `getargspec` was deprecated since Python 3.0(see [getargspec doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec)), so you are getting warnings (not errors) when it gets called. It is used a lot in sklearn.

There is some discussion of this on the scikit-learn issue tracker. It was [raised here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/5281) and [fixed here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/5301). It has been fixed for 0.17, the current stable release. If the warnings are a problem for you, you should probably just update your sklearn with `conda update scikit-learn`.